# SOAP API, WSDL and location in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, wsdl

I created a SOAP API in my Java EE project via the "Web Service from WSDL" of Netbeans. Only problem, I don't know how to access my method in my app. Here's a sample of the code:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "SalesExportService", portName = "SalesExportPort", endpointInterface = "com.supsellers.us.sales.export.SalesExport", targetNamespace = "http://us.supsellers.com/sales/export", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/NewWebServiceFromWSDL/supseller-paris.servme.fr_80/app/SalesExportService.wsdl")
@Stateless
public class SoapApi {
    @EJB
    private SaleService saleService;

        public List<com.supsellers.us.sales.export.Sale> getFranceSales() {
          // Do stuff
          return result;
    }   
}
```

I've searched on the interwebs, but I can't seems to find anything clear. Does anybody knows how can I set my own address, or at least how can I access my method in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to generate a web service client based on the WSDL of your SalesExportService . You can follow [Developing JAX-WS Web Service Clients](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html) in the NetBeans documentation.

Comment: Well, the class I put is already the one generated. I gave an URL to Netbeans feature "Web Service from WSDL" and put my method in there (it returns XML).

Comment: The class you put is the web service itself. You need to generate the web service client based on the WSDL file (the xml file you mentioned in your comment)